# CURL и время жизни cookies

Tags: curl, php, cookie

Всем здравствуйте!
Есть такой интересный вопрос:
Имеется скрипт который необходимо запускать один раз в сутки, данный скрипт средствами CURL отправляет POST запрос на некий сайт. На этом сайте необходимо авторизация, поэтому вместе со всем передается и переменная PHPSESSID, извлеченная из браузера. Все работает, но есть небольшой нюанс, срок жизни переменной «до закрытия браузера».
Так вот вопрос, что добавить к опциям CURL чтобы «браузер» считался не вновь запущеным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно каждый раз отправлять post запрос на авторизацию, считывать куки, затем отправлять эти куки с каждым запросом.

Comment: На сайте авторизация происходит через Steam Open ID, но смысл в том что после перезапуска браузера авторизация не сбрасывается, просто выдается новая переменная. Я так думаю, есть еще какая то переменная которую необходимо указывать…
Если интересно сайт dota2lounge.com

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически - можно сохранять полученную куку во внешнее хранилище (файл), при запуске скрипта - считывать и отравлять её. Будет считаться что пользователь не закрывал браузер.

Comment: Изначально так же подумал, но в файл сохраняется только та переменная которую я вводил и при следующем запуске она уже не действительна…
Я так думаю, есть еще какая то переменная которую необходимо указывать…
Если интересно сайт dota2lounge.com

Comment: Могу попробовать сделать, если еще актуально

Answer (score 1):

Кука может ставится новая при каждом обращении скрипта, после проверки валидности предыдущей куки. А в проверке валидности участвуют, и идентификатор браузера, и IP, и вообще вся доступная информация о клиенте. Если такая защита реализована, то лично я не знаю, как написать его парсер, учитывая невозможность авторизации через скрипт.